# Pop up a warning when the same item is entered twice on a sales order when the order is created/edited

Tags: javascript, duplicates, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to do a pop-up warning before the sales order is saved if the exact same item is entered twice when the order is created/modified on Netsuite. However, there is no window popping up and I am not sure what is wrong with the script. Here is what I got:

```
function validateitem (type){


var flag = true;
var numLine = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
itemArr = [];

if (type == 'item' && numLine > 0) {
       for(var i = 0; i < numLine; i++) {
           var itemSO = {};
           itemSO.id = nlapiGetLineValue('item','item',i);
           if (itemSO.id != null && itemSO.id !=''){
               for (var j = 0; j < numLine; j++){
                  if(itenArr.indexOf(itemSO[i].id) === -1) {
                      itemArr.push(itemSO[i].id);}
                  else{
                      if (!confirm('You have entered a duplicate item for this sales order. Continue?'))
                         {
                            flag = false;
                         }
                  }
              }
           }
        }
}
return flag;
}
```

Can somebody help, please?

---

Here is a slightly edited version:

```
function validateitem (){


var flag = true;
var numLine = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
itemArr = [];

if (numLine > 0) {
       for(var i = 1; i <= numLine; i++) {
           var itemSO = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','item',i);
           if (itemSO != null && itemSO !=''){
               for (var j = 1; j <= numLine; j++){
                  if(itemArr.indexOf(itemSO[i]) === -1) {
                      itemArr.push(itemSO[i]);}
                  else{
                      flag = false;
                  }
              }
           }
        }
}
if (flag == false){
    alert('You have entered the same item twice.Continue?');
}
return flag;
}
```

---

This is the complete after-edit code that works:

```
function validateitem (){

var flag = true;
var numLine = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
itemArr = [];

if (numLine > 0) {
       for(var i = 1; i <= numLine; i++) {
           var itemSO = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','item',i);
           if (itemSO != null && itemSO !=''){
               for (var j = i+1; j <= numLine; j++){
                   var itemSOplus = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','item',j);
                   if(itemSO === itemSOplus) {
                      flag = false;
                      }
              }
           }
        }
}
if (flag == false){
    alert('You have entered the same item twice.Continue?');
}
return flag;
}
```

Thanks to Krypton!!

Comment: Is this a client script? What event is it set to execute on?

Comment: Hi, this will be a save record client event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [SuiteAnswers ID 10579](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10579/kw/client%20script%20argument), there are no paramters passed to the saveRecord client event.  Therefore when your code checks the following:

```
if (type == 'item' && numLine > 0)
```

it finds that `type` equals `undefined`, so the condition is not met and the code will jump straight down to `return flag` which has been set to `true`.

Also note that in SuiteScript 1.0, line indexes start from 1 - not 0 as your code seems to assume.

EDIT - adding comment to form part of this answer:

> I'd like to understand your logic behind itemSO[i] - as itemSO is not an array. Why not just compare the item from the current line of the inner loop with the current line of the outer loop and set the flag false if they match? Also, the inner loop need only start from j = i + 1 as the previous lines would have already been compared.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Krypton! I realized that and got rid of it but the code isn't working because the loop isn't working and I couldn't figure out why... I changed the other mistake too I think it should be nlapiGetLineItemValue.

Comment: You're welcome - it's what we're here for.  If you add your revised code to your question we'll be able to see what you're talking about and hopefully work out what the problem is.

Comment: :) I just edited the question with a slightly edited code. I am new to Stackflow (and SuiteScript) so I didn't know that I could update my question too, thank you for reminding me of it!

Comment: I'd like to understand your logic behind `itemSO[i]` - as `itemSO` is not an array.  Why not just compare the item from the current line of the inner loop with the current line of the outer loop and set the flag false if they match?  Also, the inner loop need only start from `j = i + 1` as the previous lines would have already been compared.

Comment: I think you are right that's the problem I had with my loop! I am totally new to SuiteScript and am not so familiar with their functions, I thought it returns an array but it does not it only returns strings!!! I edited my code like what you suggested and it's working just fine! Thank you very much!!!!! :D

Comment: Glad you found the solution!  I've added the previous comment to my answer in case any future visitors have a similar problem.  Feel free to mark it as accepted if it helped you :)

Comment: Yeah! I have accepted your answer. Thank you for your help! :))